# Code behaviour changes when replacing internal .JSON with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've replaced my internal .JSON with an AJAX request and now my code stopped working properly. My goal is it to write a chrome extension that closes a tab if its link contains certain keywords saved in the .JSON file. This is what the code looked before:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, {
  url: [
    {urlPrefix: 'https://www.google.de/'},
    {urlPrefix: 'https://sghm.eu/iserv/login'},
  ]
});

function closeTab(e) {
  if (!e.frameId) {
    chrome.tabs.remove(e.tabId);
  }
}
```

This code worked for me.
Now the new one:

```
var obj = {};
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
        obj = JSON.parse(xhttp.response);
        console.log(obj);
    }};
    xhttp.open('GET', "banned.json", true);
    xhttp.send();


    chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, obj);

    function closeTab(e) {
      if (!e.frameId) {
        console.log("Hallo2");
        chrome.tabs.remove(e.tabId);
      }
    }
```

And the banned.json file:

```
[
    "www.google.de",
    "www.youtube.com/?gl=DE"
]
```

This code now closes every tab disreagarding the link or antything else. But I don't know why. The AJAX works as the console successfully displays the JSON array, which was previously loaded.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is asynchronous ... so `chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, obj);` is called with `obj` === `{}` - because the xmlhttprequest isn't yet even called, let alone responded

Comment: you may also notice that the code that works, the object is `{
  url: [
    {urlPrefix: 'https://www.google.de/'},
    {urlPrefix: 'https://sghm.eu/iserv/login'},
  ]
}` .. but the object you get from your XHR is `[
    "www.google.de",
    "www.youtube.com/?gl=DE"
]` - which is clearly not the same

Comment: See also [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: If that would be my mistake, in which I don't really believe in, because it doesn't work if I change it to synchronous as well, how would I solve this problem?

Comment: @Jaromanda: if I change the json to exactly what you've posted I will get an Error from chrome that states: ``Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 4``

Comment: because you're getting `undefined` somewhere

Comment: but why and were

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `obj` isn't still empty when you hit this line?:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(closeTab, obj);
```

You may reach there before `xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200` evaluates to `true` (because the `onreadystatechange` callback function runs asynchronously).

Have you tried moving the above line just underneath `console.log(obj);` in your `onreadystatechange` callback function?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I've also put a ``console.log`` in the ``closesTab`` function before and it printed the array into the console. Furthermore I changed AJAX to a synchronous request by by changing this line ``xhttp.open('GET', "banned.json", true);``to ``xhttp.open('GET', "banned.json", false);``